# Asp.net MVC - form is not sent to controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

In a Asp.net MVC view, i created a form, with a input field.

The user Sets a first name (or part of it), presses the submit button.

This is the form section:

```
<div> 
    <form action="SearchCustomer" methos="post">
        Enter first name: <input id="Text1" name="txtFirstName" type="text" />
        <br />
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Search Customer" />
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the SearchCustomer in the Controller, that gets the data from the form:

```
CustomerDal dal = new CustomerDal();
string searchValue = Request.Form["txtFirstName"].ToString();
List<Customer> customers = (from x in dal.Customers 
                            where x.FirstName.Contains(searchValue)
                            select x).ToList<Customer>();
CustomerModelView customerModelView = new CustomerModelView();
customerModelView.Customers = customers;

return View("ShowSearch", customerModelView);
```

When i run the program, and enter a first name ("Jhon" for example), the code returns to SearchCustomer function, but Request.Form  is empty.

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Typo!..instead of `methos="post"` it should be `method="post"`

Comment: and there is no action name in form action?

Comment: As @KartikeyaKhosla mentioned, you have a typo of 'methos' which should be method, and your action should be in the following format: YourControllerName/YourActionName

Comment: I fix it to method="post". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your code:

you need to provide a action name here, which should be defined in your controller(SearchController) with the same name as 'ActionName' you will put in the below code.
if SearchController is your action name then provide the controller in which the action is available.

```
<div> 
    <form action="SearchCustomer/<ActionName>" method="post">
       Enter first name: <input id="Text1" name="txtFirstName" type="text" />
       <br />
       <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Search Customer" />
   </form>
</div>
```

With Html.BeginForm :

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("<ActionName>","<ControllerName>", FormMethod.Post))
  {
      Enter first name: <input id="Text1" name="txtFirstName" type="text" />
       <br />
       <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Search Customer" />
  }
```

Comment: This approach may well end-up with another 404. Generally, `Url.Action()` or `Html.BeginForm()` should be used instead or hard-coding the path.

Answer (score 1):

Your `method` is spelled wrongly should not read `methos` but `method` like below:

```
 <form action="SearchCustomer" method="post">
            ....
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `View` is the same name as your `ActionResult` method, try this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    ... enter code
}
```

By default, it'll already be a `POST` method type and it'll be directed to the `ActionResult`. One thing to make sure of: You will need the `[HttpPost]` attribute on your `ActionResult` method so the form knows where to go:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchCustomer (FormCollection form)
{
     // Pull from the form collection
     string searchCriteria = Convert.ToString(form["txtFirstName"]);
     // Or pull directly from the HttpRequest
     string searchCriteria = Convert.ToString(Request["txtFirstName"]);
     .. continue code
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Set [HttpPost] on your controller.

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SearchFunction(string txtFirstName)
  {
          CustomerDal dal = new CustomerDal();
         string searchValue = txtFirstName;
         List<Customer> customers = (from x in dal.Customers 
                            where x.FirstName.Contains(searchValue)
                            select x).ToList<Customer>();
         CustomerModelView customerModelView = new CustomerModelView();
        customerModelView.Customers = customers;
       return View("ShowSearch", customerModelView);
  }
```

Comment: my twitter handler : @mohitdagar80